# How to make Xamarin Forms text size depending on OS settings text size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I would like to make it possible for users to make text size bigger in my App and thereby easier to see the texts.
I don't want to do this inside my App setting when both iOS and Android have this directly build inside the OS.

On Android the Xamarin Forms Label, Entry, etc. text sizes adjust according to Android text size setting.
But that is not the case, when I try the same App on iOS.

How do I make this work on iOS?

Examples would be great :-)

Comment: Have you tried to bind the Font size ? Not sure if it works , but i think it worths the try then you can change it based on the platform from the viewmodel

Comment: @BraveHeart No, I haven't tried that. It's not the platform that I need to depend on, but the platforms general Text size (which works on Android). Do you have any ideas to that? :-)

Answer (score 1):

In iOS code (AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching), subscribe to UIApplication.Notifications.ObserveContentSizeCategoryChanged

If you are ok with using the same scaling factor for all of your styles, you can use the same scaling mechanism Xamarin Forms uses for the [NamedSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.namedsize?view=xamarin-forms) FontSizes.

Have the ObserveContentSizeCategoryChanged handler call a method in Xamarin Forms code, scaling and setting the font size on all of your styles.

```
        private int ScaleFontSize(int fontSize)
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                //Xamarin Forms only scales named font sizes on iOS
                //Manually scale fonts using the same factor
                //https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Forms.cs#L267
                return (int)(Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Body, this) / 17f * fontSize);
            }
            return fontSize;
        }
```

Alternatively, if you want to use different type scales for different text styles, you can set your FontSizes in your AppDelegate.

```
        private static void UpdateFontStyles()
        {
            var app = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current;

            app.Resources["Title1FontSize"] = GetScaledFontSize(28, UIFontTextStyle.Title1);
            app.Resources["Title2FontSize"] = GetScaledFontSize(20, UIFontTextStyle.Title2);
            app.Resources["Title3FontSize"] = GetScaledFontSize(18, UIFontTextStyle.Title3);
            app.Resources["BodyFontSize"] = GetScaledFontSize(16, UIFontTextStyle.Body);
            app.Resources["Caption1FontSize"] = GetScaledFontSize(14, UIFontTextStyle.Caption1);
            app.Resources["Caption2FontSize"] = GetScaledFontSize(12, UIFontTextStyle.Caption2);
        }

        private static double GetScaledFontSize(int fontSize, UIFontTextStyle textStyle)
        {
            return new UIFontMetrics(textStyle.GetConstant()).GetScaledValue(fontSize);
        }
```

Call UpdateFontStyles in FinishedLaunching to update styles with the initial text size as well as in UIApplication.Notifications.ObserveContentSizeCategoryChanged

App.xaml

```
    <x:Double x:Key="Title1FontSize">28</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="Title2FontSize">20</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="Title3FontSize">18</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="BodyFontSize">16</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="Caption1FontSize">14</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="Caption2FontSize">12</x:Double>

    <Style x:Key="Title1Style" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource YourFont}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource Title1FontSize}" />
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a custom renderer (or a [platform specific effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction#:%7E:text=Effects%20simplify%20this%20process%2C%20allowing,appropriate%20control%20in%20a%20Xamarin.)) and the `traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection)). You'll need to do something like this:

```cs
var originalFontSize = xamLabelElement.FontSize;
xamLabelElement.FontSize = originalFontSize * GetFontMultiplier(iOSUILablel.TraitCollection.PreferredContentSizeCategory)
// ...
float GetFontMultiplier(string preferredContentSizeCategory)
{
    switch (preferredContentSizeCategory)
    {
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryXS": return 0.5f;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryS": return 0.8f;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryM": return 1;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryL": return 1.5f;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryXL": return 2;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryXXL": return 2.5f;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryXXXL": return 3;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityM": return 1;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityL": return 1.5f;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityXL": return 2;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityXXL": return 2.5f;
        case "UICTContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityXXXL": return 3;
        default: return 1;
    }
}
```

*Note that this is untested code. It's just to give you a general idea.*

Look at this article for more info:
https://betterprogramming.pub/proper-font-scaling-matters-to-your-users-515b1b878606

Answer (score -1):

You can define global style inside App.Xaml like this:

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="Font_Small" x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="12" Android="10" />
<OnPlatform x:Key="Font_Medium" x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="16" Android="14" />
<OnPlatform x:Key="Font_Large" x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="20" Android="18" />

<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="ListHeaderTextStyle">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="{StaticResource Font_Large}" Phone="{StaticResource Font_Medium}"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

For just example I have added few font sizes you can define your own and use as per requirement.